# adding attribute values by using translate

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i've the below xml

```
<table>
<tgroup cols="7" align="left" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
<colspec colwidth="20pt" colname="c1"/>
<colspec colwidth="70pt" colname="c2"/>
<colspec colwidth="10pt" colname="c3"/>
<colspec colwidth="20pt" colname="c4"/>
<colspec colwidth="75pt" colname="c5"/>
</tgroup>
</table>
```

here i want to add all the colwidths.
when i use `sun()` it is showing Nan result as the colwidth is having `pt` at the end, i need to use a `translate()` and then `sum()` function, please let me know how i can do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you're trying to do something like "for each `colspec`, strip off the trailing `pt` from its `colwidth` and convert to a number, then sum all of the resulting numbers together".  In XSLT 2.0 you can do this with

```
sum(path/to/colspec/xs:integer(substring-before(@colwidth, 'pt')))
```

(or `xs:decimal` if the colwidths are not all integers) - `path/to/colspec` needs to be replaced with whatever is the correct path from the current context node to the set of all `colspec` elements, it might be `tgroup/colspec` if you're currently on the `table` element or `../colspec` if you're currently on one of the `colspec` elements.

In XSLT 1.0 you can't do it in a single XPath expression because you can only `sum` a node set directly, you can't massage the individual values before summing them.  In 1.0 I'd probably go for tail-recursive templates with an accumulator parameter:

```
<xsl:template match="colspec" mode="sumwidth">
  <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::colspec[1]" mode="sumwidth">
    <xsl:with-param name="total"
         select="$total + substring-before(@colwidth, 'pt')" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="colspec[not(following-sibling::colspec)]" mode="sumwidth">
  <xsl:param name="total" select="0" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$total + substring-before(@colwidth, 'pt')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and then call this using

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="colspec[1]" mode="sumwidth" />
```

Comment: Hi @Ian, Thanks for your answer, but here it is just giving 0, i use this is giving me the same number as the colwidth, but not sum, just want o know, do i need to add a for-each loop?

Comment: also when i use `<div class="a">
<xsl:for-each select="../colspec">
<xsl:value-of select="sum(xs:integer(substring-before(@colwidth, 'pt')))"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</div> ` from colspan tag it is giving me output as `<div class="a">2070102075</div>`

Comment: @user2423959: Since my solution worked in the first context but not in the second context I think you have to select your _current node_ right before you call either Ian's or my solution.

Comment: @user2423959 you shouldn't need a for-each as there's an implicit iteration within the XPath, but you need to make sure you are really applying the path to the nodes you think you are.  From your for-each example it looks like you need `sum(../colspec/xs:integer(...))`

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts this worked and +1 for detailed explanation.